# Regex - Expression for matching international characters doesn't work when I add ^ $

Tags: python, regex, internationalization

Trying to get a regular expression in Python to match word characters, international word characters (eg chinese) and can't get my head around it so need some help.

I tried this :

`ur'(?ui)[\w]'` and it matches for example : "斗牛"

but if I also put a question mark or semicolon in the string (eg. "斗牛?!" ),  it also matches.

Next, I tried to add the symbol for start of string and end of string eg. : `ur'^(?ui)[\w]$'` and it doesn't return a match for "斗牛", even though from what I can tell it should do?!

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input contains *two* codepoints, so you need to match *more than one character*:

```
ur'^(?ui)[\w]+$'
```

You don't need the `[...]` character class here as `\w` is its own full class:

```
ur'(?ui)^\w+$'
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(ur'(?ui)^\w+$')
>>> pattern.search(u'斗牛')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10884e168>
>>> pattern.search(u'斗牛?') is None
True
```

Comment: Works! Thanks for this, still learning my way through Regex. I wasn't passing the string as a unicode string, just regular. :/

Comment: @BogdiG: I considered that possibility, but your pattern still failed even when using a `unicode` string input.